# How to edit gitignore file

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gitignore

I started TheOdinProject on Ubuntu 18.4 and in the Git section it tells me to edit the .gitignore file. I already created it using `touch .gitignore` and it is showing up when i type `ls -la` but I don't see it in Files. In the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVsySz-h9r4 that is referenced the file is already open and there isn't an explanation on how to open it.
**How do I open the .gitignore file from Terminal in order to add something like `.DS_Store` in it?**

Comment: added answer with screen-shots and command-line commands, so that you don't hv to learn or use any editor :)

Comment: May I know the reasons of downvote, I explained the answer with screen-shots and provided solution which anybody without having prior knowledge of vim on linux can do :( ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`.gitignore` files are hidden on *nix operating systems because of their dot prefix ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory)).  However you can access them as normal from the shell.  e.g. `nano .gitignore`.

Comment: No problem, happy to help 

Answer (score 1):

`ls -lah` (the h flag is for hidden files)

You can open and edit it with any terminal text editor (or GUI code text editor)

Comment: No [`-a`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) is to show hidden files; `-h` means "*print sizes in human readable format*".

Comment: @phd oh yeah, you're right. I was thrown off when he said he couldn't find the file with `ls -la`

Answer (score -1):

You need need to even use any editor(Vi or GUI based) to simply add the `.DS_Store` in your newly created `.gitignore` file, following are the screen-shot of commands, which I just did on my new repo to explain you better.

Step 1, to see the hidden `.gitignore` file, use the `ls -la` command, which would show the file as below

[image]

Step 2: Add `.DS_Store` to your `.gitignore` file, use below commands

```
echo .DS_Store >> .gitignore
```

Step 3. check the content of `.gitignore` file

```
cat .gitignore
```

The below image shows adding and checking the content of `.gitignore`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question so thorougly! I think the "nano .gitignore" answer is a bit faster for editing multiple lines of code, but yours is a neat trick for quick editing I will keep in mind in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @leonbeckert, thanks I could be of some help, I was bit frustrated when someone without going into details downvoted my answer :( and yeah when you need to add single line and quickly verify this is the fastest you can get 